# The method 'Union' is not supported. Declaring type: System.Linq.Queryable (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, union, concatenation, iqueryable

I have two IQueryables that i need to merge. This is my code:

```
IQueryable<SearchResultsItem> resourceQueriable = GetIndexQueriable(ResourceIndexName);
IQueryable<SearchResultsItem> resourceQueriableResults = resourceQueriable.Where(x => x.DatabaseName == Database);

IQueryable<SearchResultsItem> resourcePageQueriable = GetIndexQueriable(ResourcePageIndexName);
IQueryable<SearchResultsItem> resourcePageQueriableResults =
    resourcePageQueriable.Where(x => x.DatabaseName == Database);

string ResourceTypeGuid = ItemReference.ItemReference.BBB_ResourceTypes_ProductGuide.InnerItem.ID.ToString().ConvertToShortId();

resourceQueriableResults = resourceQueriableResults.Where(x => x.ResourceType == ResourceTypeGuid);
resourcePageQueriableResults = resourcePageQueriableResults.Where(x => Boolean.Parse(x.IncludeInGuides));

IQueryable<SearchResultsItem> concatResults = resourceQueriableResults.Union(resourcePageQueriableResults);

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> namePathPairs =
    concatResults
        .Where(x => x.DatabaseName == Database)
        .OrderBy(y => y.NavTitle)
        .ToList() //Enumerate the query before translating it.
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.NavTitle.CleanNavTitle(), x.Url));

return namePathPairs;
```

The error is thrown on `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> namePathPairs = concatResults....`

Why is it throwing this error, and how can I merge my two IQueryables? I previously only had one IQueryable, and this worked fine

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> namePathPairs =
            resourceQueriable
                .Where(x => x.DatabaseName == Database)
                .OrderBy(y => y.NavTitle)
                .ToList() //Enumerate the query before translating it.
                .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.NavTitle.CleanNavTitle(), x.Url));
```

But now that I'm using the merged IQueryable on that line, it's not working.

Comment: Could you try to do `Boolean.Parse(x.IncludeInGuides)` outside the query expression?